Parking Function Concept
I am having trouble understanding the concept of parking functions. How does Def. 2 relate to Def. 1?

Def 1: the number of sequences of length n
of positive integers in the range from 1
to n
, with the property that, for every $i$
up to the sequence length, the sequence contains at least $i$
values that are at most $i$.


Def 2: A sequence of $n$ drivers in cars travel down a one-way street having $n$ parking spaces, with each driver having a preferred parking space. Each driver travels until reaching their preferred space, and then parks in the first available spot. A parking function describes preferences for which all cars can park.

Additionally, can someone please clear up this proof for the number of parking functions of size $n$? I am not following the proof:

On a circular one-way road with $n+1$ spaces, each of $n$ cars will always be able to park, no matter what preference each driver has for their starting space. There are
$(n+1)^n$ choices for the preferences, each of which leaves one vacant space. All spaces are symmetric to each other, so by symmetry, there are $(n+1)^{n-1}$ choices for preferences that leave space $n+1$ as the vacant space. These choices are exactly the parking functions.

I am also having trouble visualizing how this connects to the permutations of integers. I would appreciate any clarification/explanation.

Perhaps an example would help illustrate the connection between the two definitions. Consider the sequence $(1,1,4,2)$. This sequence satisfies the first definition. We can think of the $i$th element of this sequence as the preference of car $i$; so the first car prefers space $1$ and so on. Under these preferences, car $1$ will park in space $1$, car $2$ in space $2$, car $3$ in space $4$, and car $4$ in space $3$. So this sequence satisfies the second definition.
A non-example would be the sequence $(2,2,2)$. This does not satisfy the first definition, since there is no element of value at most $1$. Thinking about the cars, we see that car $1$ parks in space $2$, car $2$ in space $3$, and now car $3$ cannot park. This is because there is no car parking in space $1$, so three cars are left to park in two spots. In general, if there are fewer than $i$ values that are at most $i$, it means that there are at least $n-i+1$ values greater than $i$, which leads to a shortage in parking spaces; there are at least $n-i+1$ cars with at most $n-i$ spots that want to park after space $i$. And this is the only thing that can go wrong, so these definitions are equivalent. I hope this makes sense.
With regards to the proof, on a circular road, the cars can loop around, so all cars will find a spot. There are $(n+1)$ spaces, and $n$ cars, which gives $(n+1)^n$ possible preferences. By symmetry, there are $(n+1)^{n-1}$ preferences that leave the $(n+1)$th space vacant. Now, why are these configurations exactly the parking functions? Because the $(n+1)$th spot is vacant if and only if all cars find a space in the first $n$ spaces. Alternatively, you can observe that the non-parking functions are exactly the ones where $(n+1)$th space is occupied, which occurs if and only if all valid spaces in the first $n$ spaces were taken for some car.
